# How to retrieve a Menu Name by Menu Location with ACF fields

Tags: menus, advanced-custom-fields

What WordPress function can be used to retrieve a Menu Name using the Menu Location as parameter?

Answer (score 0):

To retrieve the Menu Name:

```
$menu_name = wp_get_nav_menu_name("menu-products");
```

Then, using the menu name you can get data like the nav menu:

```
$term = get_term_by('name', $menu_name, 'nav_menu');
```

And using the term taxonomy ID you can pull the ACF fields

```
$menu_id = $term->term_taxonomy_id;
$post_id = 'term_'.$menu_id;
$field = get_field('my_acf_field', $post_id);
```

To retrieve list of menu Items:

```
$menu = wp_get_nav_menu_items( $term );
```

On the CMS side, the ACF Group, you need to select the Rule:
`Menu Item | Is equal to | Product Location`